# background image crop height when the screen is reduced

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image

```
<div class="blog-img" style="background-image: url('{{ $blog->imgUrl }}');"></div>
```

The problem is that I can't render this image without setting the styles to a fixed height and width

CSS:

```
.blog-img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: 100% auto; 
  background-position: unset;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Everything outputs almost the way I need, but the only thing is the problem with the height. When I reduce the screen, I need to cut off the extra piece of the block, but this does not happen due to the fact that a fixed height is set

[image]

How can I make it so that when the screen is reduced, this piece that I selected on the screen is cut off?

Comment: The `width: 600px;` is not going to fit on smaller screens either ... Most likely, you want a "responsive" element, that goes over the full available width, but keeps the necessary aspect ratio (which you then would need to know upfront)? Then go check out [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio), or research the "padding-bottom hack".

Comment: Check object-fit property also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options as far as I see it:

1. Set `aspect-ratio` on the div that matches the aspect ratio of your picture. This will make sure that for any width of the div it will have the height to match the aspect ratio of the picture so it won't be stretched or cropped. make sure to use `background-size:contain`.
2. Set `background-size` to `cover` so there will automatic crop on the image but it would fit all sizes of the div. Tip: you can adjust the `background-position` property to make sure the part that you care about most in the picture is visible for example `center center`.

If you just care about the picture being shown properly go with the second option. However, if you have content inside that div or the size of the div is not under your control go with the first.

Comment: `aspect-ratio` does not work at all when I add

Comment: @baby in your css remove `height: 500px;`, maybe better also to set `width:100%`. If you give the exact dimesions of the div, then aspect-ratio property is ignored.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! `aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;` was perfect for my image